# Writing text to a file [PHP, HTML]

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to write text to the bottom of an existing text file but don't have a clue how to do it.

I have tried the code below but it don't work.
The text file location is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.txt`

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $file = fopen("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.txt\\","a+");
        fwrite($file,$email);
        fclose($file); 
        print_r(error_get_last());
    }
?>

<form action= "" method="post" name="form">
<input type="text" name="email">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors from the PHP interpreter when running this script? Why do you have two backslashes at the end of the file path?

Comment: The backslashes should either be doubled up (\\\) to avoid escaping, or replaced with forwards slashes (`/`). The ones at the end look wrong too, as Kyle says.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
file_put_contents("file_path", your_content, FILE_APPEND);
```

so in your case...

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        file_put_contents("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.txt", $email, FILE_APPEND);
    }
?>
```

Documentation [here](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents).

Comment: sorry I'm new to PHP, where exactly would that go?

Comment: See edit. It just replaces your fopen, write, and close calls.

Comment: Oh I tried that but It didnt work, thats why I wondered where it went because maybe I done it wrong? But it dont work

Comment: Make sure your path is correct. Documentation for this function can be found here with examples: http://us2.php.net/file_put_contents

Comment: It's not working for some reason and if I was to add upload.php to the form action"" and put the php in the upload.php it goes to a white page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $write = fopen('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.txt', 'a');
  fwrite($write, 'Email: '.$email ."\n");
  fclose($write);
}
?>

<form method="POST" name="form">
<input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
</form>
```